# MySQL Varchar Primary Key With Not Null Constraint Accepting Nulls

Tags: mysql, primary-key, null

I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `invite` (
  `id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_i_e` (`email`)
)
```

My goal with the not null constraint on `id` is to make sure there are no null values as the primary key, and to ultimately fail to insert.

However, not specifying the id on insert works just fine:

```
INSERT INTO invite (`email`) VALUES ('e@mail.com');
```

There is an 1364 warning specifying `Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`, but the insert succeeds just fine.

It looks like MySQL is using the not null constraint to turn this into a non null (blank) value at insert.

If I actually specify `null` as a value of `id`, the insert fails as expected.

Without having a trigger to stop empty strings being inserted, how can I stop this scenario from happening, i.e force a non empty string value to be specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent this insert from occurring, [turn on strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40889485/1797579).

```
mysql> set session sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO invite (`email`) VALUES ('e@mail.com');
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
mysql> select * from invite;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Note: Be sure to follow the description in the link I provided, NOT copy my command regarding setting `sql_mode`. Otherwise you may disable other settings.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I'll probably not turn this setting on then and just get used to the quirk (as it seems to me).